# Style sheet to be imported based on the current active component in a multi-page React app with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The current situation is that I have multiple components that each has a different style sheet and I started to merge them all.

And here is the issue, every style sheet is imported globally* when importing the components in the main index.js file.

```
// Auth stylesheet found in Auth.js(component)
import './style.sass';

// Auth component being imported in index.js file
import Auth from "./components/Auth/Auth";
```

And here comes the conflict part, especially for the upper stack of the DOM container, like document, #root...

Is there any way that each component's stylesheet to be imported when its component is rendered to the DOM, it's quite tedious that every stylesheet needs to be imported when one component it's actively being rendered?

Here is my **index.js** file, just in case, where I defined my custom routes that correspond to different parts of the website.

```
...

let store = createStore(rootReducer, app, applyMiddleware(
    ThunkMiddleware,
    logger
));

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome}/>
                <Route exact path="/auth" component={Auth}/>
                <Route exact path="/main" component={Main}/>
                ...
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: So you want to lazy-load stylesheets? That might create a bad UX because an unstyled component might show up for a flash the first time you visit a component because loading stylesheets takes time.

Comment: If by lazy-loading stylesheets, you mean being imported before component to be rendered then yes.

Comment: I generally use `styled-components` for my react projects, but I'm positive that you can import each component's CSS on the component file, not on the global `index.js`. So for your example, import the style on the Auth's component file. Is that what you want? Then, your index.js wouldn't need to import all the css, only the components

Comment: @pavlag I made an edit, basically each component is importing his stylesheet, thus if index.js imports every component, it will include also every stylesheet, so no, doesn't work as I would like.

Comment: oh I see. then I would maybe follow the suggestion of @Li357 and look for lazy loading the css only when loading the component, but I don't think it will be possible, because, as you said, you import the files right in the index.js. A way to do it is to give each Route a `classname` and scope all but the common/base css in each file to the corresponding class

Comment: I would also recommend taking a look at styled-components and, if your project is still in the beginnings, maybe give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use styles are either 
1. Importing them and using the classname attribute on the component.
2. In-line styles. By calling stylesheet directly on the component.

```
<form style={{backgroundColor: ‘black’}}> <\form>
```

Comment: Then how I would be able to inject css style to DOM elements like document & window in reactish way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to control this using

before the class

```
let cssloaded = false;
```

`let cssloaded = false;`
loading dis in the render

```
 if(cssloaded === false){ 
        `cssloader = true;`
         import ('.././style/index.css');
          import ('.././style/css/style.css');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  Would it be possible to wrap that code into a `code block` to make it a bit easier to read?  I think you just need to add back ticks around it.